# How to read the row number with having column data?

Tags: java, winappdriver

I'm automating an app and using `winappdriver` tool with java language for the same. I am selecting a row and clicking on that row in GUI. Here I am trying to delete a row. So I have a sequence number and with that sequence number I need to delete the row.

This is the snap of UI Spy :

[image]

Here sequence number value is 5, but I want to click the row 3.

```
//here loopng through each row by row..
String seqNoData=alEvents.get(i).sequenceNumber; //data (sequcenceNumber) from db
List<WebElement> pbp_insert = mainEntrySession.findElementByName("DataGridView").findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'table')]"));                                     
                    List<WebElement> pbp_insert_grid_cells = pbp_insert.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
                
          //    pbp_insert_grid_cells--contains all cellvalues  
                    for(int cellIndex = 14;cellIndex < pbp_insert_grid_cells.size();cellIndex=cellIndex+17) //14 th column is sequence number
                    {

                        rowSequenceNo = pbp_insert_grid_cells.get(cellIndex).getText(); //read sequence number from gui
                        
                        if(seqNoData==rowSequenceNo)
                        {
```

//sequence number 5==5 matching, how to get the sequence number row 3 and row 3 parent
//here how to fetch parent from child to click on that row..
}

Comment: Can you clear out what is your issue. Heading says _How to read the row number with having column data?_ and question says _I am getting very slow to select. how to get row 3 click on very fast ?_

Comment: Ho did you located sequence number value 5 in your code?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Actually, in my gui screen , one sequence number column is there, so i am reading from there...just getText().. and convert it into integer

Comment: I mean what is the code? How do you locate that element where you invoke getText() then?

Comment: @AlexeyR.  please check my code..how to get the parent element Row 3 from child sequence number row 3

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to find the element's parent if you already have a child in `WebElement` when you use `WinAppDriver`. However you can use the work-around the idea of which I demonstrate in the below example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
    WindowsDriver driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
    WebElement element = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("num8Button");
    WebElement parentElement = findParent(element, driver);
    System.out.println(parentElement.getAttribute("Name"));
    driver.quit();
}

static WebElement findParent(WebElement child, WebDriver driver){
    String automationId = child.getAttribute("AutomationId");
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[./*[@AutomationId='" + automationId + "']]"));
}
```

**Code explanation:**

Basically, here you introduce helper method that takes your element, extracts `AutomationId` attribute value and builds xpath query starting from the top of the dom. That query is built in the way to find all the elements which have at least one child element having the given `AutomationId`. So if you have the structure like this:

```
root
|
+-- el1
|    |
|    +-- el2 [AutomationId = 'blahblahId']
|
+-- el3
```

And if you pass `el2` to that method, then it extracts value `blahblahId` and build the following xpath query: `//*[./*[@AutomationId='blahblahId']]`. This query will return element `el1`

Comment: @Anthony see the explanation in update

Comment: please check my question , i have edited